# How to store multiple array in laravel in two tables?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables `products` and `colors`.

I want to store multiple rows in multiple tables within my database. My controller is currently not storing multiple values, it is only saving one row in my products and item lists tables.

blade

```
<div class="row no-gutters mb-1">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="color_name" class="ml-1">نام رنگ:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color_name" name="color_name[]" class="form-control w-auto d-inline">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="color_code" class="ml-1">کد رنگ:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color_code" name="color_code[]" class="form-control w-75 d-inline jscolor">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <a onclick="addColor()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
        <a onclick="deleteColor()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

ProductController.php

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
    $product = Product::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'latin' => $request->latin,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'discount' => $request->discount,
        'coupon' => $request->coupon,
        'order_product' => 0,
        'body' => $request->body,
        'keywords' => $request->keywords,
        'descriptions' => $request->descriptions,
    ]);
    $color = new Color;
    $color->product_id = $product->id;
    $color->color_code = $product->color_code;
    $color->color_name = $product->color_name;
    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

Comment: What does the `Product::create` method do?

Comment: This method do for create `title`, `price`, `coupon` and ....... of products.

Comment: Well, you only create one product. Are there multiple products on the page?

Comment: Yea! But does it do an UPDATE or an INSERT

Comment: with `insert`...

Comment: @brombeer, Yes I want to save title, price, coupon and ....... in products table, and I want to save multiple `color_name[]` and `color_code[]` in colors table.